# How do I get my python object back from a QVariant in PyQt4?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qvariant, qabstractitemmodel

I am creating a subclass of `QAbstractItemModel` to be displayed in an `QTreeView`.

My `index()` and `parent()` function creates the `QModelIndex` using the `QAbstractItemModel` inherited function `createIndex` and providing it the `row`, `column`, and `data` needed. Here, for testing purposes, data is a Python string.

```
class TestModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self)

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if parent.isValid():
            return self.createIndex(row, column, "bar")
        return self.createIndex(row, column, "foo")

    def parent(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            if index.data().data() == "bar":                          <--- NEVER TRUE
                return self.createIndex(0, 0, "foo")
        return QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            if index.data().data() == "bar":                          <--- NEVER TRUE
                return 0
        return 1

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid():
            return index.data().data()                                <--- CANNOT DO ANYTHING WITH IT
        return "<None>"
```

Within the `index()`, `parent()`, and `data()` functions I need to get my data back. It comes as a `QVariant`. How do I get my Python object back from the QVariant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key thing is to use `internalPointer()` directly on the `QModelIndex`, not dealing with the `QVariant` at all.

```
class TestModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, plan):
        QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self)

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if not parent.isValid():
            return self.createIndex(row, column, "foo")
        return self.createIndex(row, column, "bar")

    def parent(self, index):
         if index.internalPointer() == "bar":
            return self.createIndex(0, 0, "foo")
        return QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, index):
        if index.internalPointer() == "bar":
            return 0
        return 1

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == 0:  # Qt.DisplayRole
            return index.internalPointer()
        else:
            return None
```

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried this?

```
my_python_object = my_qvariant.toPyObject()
```

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qvariant.html#toPyObject (just for completeness, but there isn't much to see there...)

Comment: This answer is more inline with the initial question. It helped me thanks